# Сombine elements in array by JSON's items

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I have simple array with JSON items:

```
array = [
 {number: 9, item: 'Item 1', descripton: 'abc'},
 {number: 5, item: 'Item 2', descripton: 'def'},
 {number: 9, item: 'Item 2', descripton: 'ghi'},
 {number: 9, item: 'Item 1', descripton: 'xyz'},
]
```

how can I get arrays with same parameters of JSON key ('number', 'item'), and get new array like this:

```
array = [
 [
  {number: 9, item: 'Item 1', descripton: 'abc'},
  {number: 9, item: 'Item 1', descripton: 'xyz'},
 ],
 [
  {number: 5, item: 'Item 2', descripton: 'def'},
 ],
 [
  {number: 9, item: 'Item 2', descripton: 'ghi'},
 ] 
]
```

I tried using the `.sort()` and `.filter()` methods, but I can not get result where I need.

Comment: So *how* are you using `sort` and *why* are you trying to use `filter`?

Comment: Extract the number of item with x_n = Number(x['item'][x['item'].length-1]); and order with this value using custom sort function

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [
 {
  number: 9,
  item: 'Item 1',
  descripton: 'abc'
 },
 {
  number: 5,
  item: 'Item 2',
  descripton: 'def'
 },
 {
  number: 9,
  item: 'Item 2',
  descripton: 'ghi'
 },
 {
  number: 9,
  item: 'Item 1',
  descripton: 'xyz'
 },
];
array.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.item > b.item) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return -1;
      }
    });
    console.log(array);

If you run the above js you will get output like this..
[
  { number: 9, item: 'Item 1', descripton: 'xyz' },
  { number: 9, item: 'Item 1', descripton: 'abc' },
  { number: 9, item: 'Item 2', descripton: 'ghi' },
  { number: 5, item: 'Item 2', descripton: 'def' }
]
```

Comment: Ty so much, it is cool, but can you combane the same JSON's items in array? 

[
  [ { number: 9, item: 'Item 1', descripton: 'xyz' },
  { number: 9, item: 'Item 1', descripton: 'abc' }],
  [{ number: 9, item: 'Item 2', descripton: 'ghi' }],
  [{ number: 5, item: 'Item 2', descripton: 'def' }]
]

Comment: Elements with same 'number' and 'item'

Comment: Then in end add this
console.log(JSON.stringify(array))